# For loop in for loop(python) not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested-loops

This program is supposed to remove duplicate elements from a list but it doesn't seem to work,

```
 import random
 def func():
    a=random.sample(range(10),7)
    b=random.sample(range(10),6)
    list=a+b
    print(list)
    print(len(list))
    for x in list:
        for y in list:
            if x==y and list.index(x)!=list.index(y):
                list.remove(y)
print(func())
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[2, 6, 4, 7, 0, 9, 3, 8, 3, 5, 7, 0, 1]
13
None
```

Comment: The function does not `return` anything so there is nothing to `print`.

Comment: btw Don't use built-in names for your variables. You are using `list`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything from `func()`, so it defaults to returning `None`.

In order to return something, use `return`.

```
 import random
 def func():
     a=random.sample(range(10),7)
     b=random.sample(range(10),6)
     list=a+b
     print(list)
     print(len(list))
     for x in list:
         for y in list:
             if x==y and list.index(x)!=list.index(y):
                 list.remove(y)
     return(list)
 print(func())
```

There's also a much simpler way of doing this.

```
import random


def func():
    a=random.sample(range(10),7)
    b=random.sample(range(10),6)

    random_list = a + b
    print(random_list, len(random_list))

    seen = set()
    nondup_list = [x for x in random_list if not (x in seen or seen.add(x))]

    return(nondup_list)


print(func())
```

The [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) can only contain unique elements by definition - therefore, casting to a set removes duplicates. It is, however, unordered by default, so instead of just casting to a set we add members to a new list one by one, checking they're not already in our new list and, if they're not, adding them to our `seen` set. Credit for that method to [Martin Broadhurst](http://www.martinbroadhurst.com/removing-duplicates-from-a-list-while-preserving-order-in-python.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'll put that as an answer. but note that you should probably clarify your title.

Firstly, if your main goal is to remove duplicate, your best bet is to cast your `list` as a `set` since `set` don't allow duplicate internally.

```
a=random.sample(range(10),7)
b=random.sample(range(10),6)
my_list=a+b
print(set(list))
```

Also note that you could use that for a better output:

```
a=random.sample(range(10),7)
b=random.sample(range(10),6)
my_list=a+b
print (','.join(str(v) for v in set(my_list)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides for all the other good answers how to get the result you're looking for the logic is flawed.

`a_list.index(value)` will always return the first instance of `value` inside the list.

in your instance `list.index(x) != list.index(y)` will never be true since you will always be matching the first occurrence of the value represented by `x` and `y`.

Therefore whenever `x == y` then `list.index(x)` will always equal `list.index(y)`.

Comment: Please explain ,why always only the first indexes will be compared,there  will be cases when x and y are equal and their indexes are different.

Comment: In this for loop x and y are the actual values in your list not the index. So the first time through the inner loop `x = 2` and `y = 2` etc. When you get to the point that x is the first 3 and y is the second 3 you expect to remove 3. However `list.index(x)` & `list.index(y)`  are both really `list.index(3)` this will always return `6` which is the first index in the list that contains the value `3`.

Answer (score 0):

I've used indexing to retrieve elements from a list,

```
import random
def func():
    a=random.sample(range(10),7)
    b=random.sample(range(10),6)
    list1=a+b
    print(list1)
    print(len(list1))
    for i in range(len(list1)-1):
        for j in range(i+1,len(list1)):
            if list1[i]==list1[j]:
                list1.remove(list1[j])
                break
    return list1            

print(func())
```

as others are solving this using set() which is impressive, but i guess you are a beginner like me so i wrote this program from basics just like you.